# How to save folds?

Tags: folding

I made a few folds in my file, but they were gone after I closed it. I'd like to save them somehow somewhere, and teach vim to automatically load them when I open this file.

Comment: You can start from [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip991) :)